# Subdomain Points to Subfolder and need .Htaccess to Redirect to a Wordpress Multi-Site Sub-Site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

Ok, since a subdomain has to point to a real place, I created the subdomain pra.aquizone.net to point to aquizone.net/blogs/links/pra.  The Wordpress (WP) Multi-site (MU) that I want to point to is aquizone.net/blogs/pra where that directory is virtually handled by the WP MU and the .htaccess under aquizone.net/blogs.

I am assuming that I can change the .htaccess file under aquizone.net/blogs/link/pra to point to aquizone.net/blogs/pra and have the subdomain wind up resulting at aquizone.net/blogs/pra.  Only everything I have tried does not work.  Here is my currect .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pra.*$ http://aquilone.me/blogs/pra/ [R=301,L]
```

The AddHandler was placed there by the subdomain creation and taking it out or leaving it makes no difference.  It does not work. You can go to http://aquilone.me/blogs/links/pra/ and see it does not redirect.

How can I change this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on your provider, you can point your subdomain towards the same directory of your top level domain, i.e.:
 example.com -> /public_html/
 this.example.com -> /public_html/

But your question is not clear about what you are trying to do. Is it a subdomains network or is it a subfolders network? If subdomains, try to change the directory your subdomain points to as in the example above, and create the blog inside wp-admin/network/ If subfolders, then you don't need the subdomain, unless you really want to redirect it to a subfolder just like an easier to remember shortcut, in that case you don't need a RewriteRule, WP takes care of the virtual subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what had happened.  Anything from the aquizone.net/blogs forward was being handled by Wordpress and the .htaccess setup at this subfolder.  Therefore, having the redirect point to aquizone.net/blogs/links/pra and in that folder have the .htaccess to then point it where I want was never being seen.

To fix this, I moved the "links" directory to aquizone.net/links.  Placing inside the ./pra/ folder with the .htaccess file.  The subdomain redirects to this folder and then the .htaccess redirects this to the correct wordpress multisite subdirectory.

Of course it would be immensely easier if you could access a multisite by a hard link (for example aquizone.net/blogs/index.php?id=2) and could set the subdoman to redirect directly to that.  But what I have is working.